# How to fix incompatible types with array of objects in list

Tags: java, list, object, casting, arraylist

I have a problem with the code below. Compiler says incompatible types, java.lang.object[][] required but found java.lang.object[].

Anyone have an idea why this is? I've found some about generics that gives problems here but no solution to my problem.

```
Object sqlQuery[][] = null;

List<Object[]> sqlLista = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
   while (resultSet.next()) {
      sqlLista.add(new Object[] { false, resultSet.getString("MMITNO"), null, null, null, null, null } );
   }

sqlQuery = sqlLista.toArray();
```

edit: I have edited the code above as i see i had made a mistake with the dimensions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling the [parameterless overload of `toArray()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28%29), which returns `Object[]`. You can't assign an `Object[]` to an `Object[][]` variable.

Now it seems to me that you possibly *actually* want to make `sqlQuery` an `Object[][][]` instead of an `Object[][]`, so that you get one two-dimensional array per entry in the result set. You'd then have:

```
// Please use this form rather than putting the brackets after the name
// - it keeps all the type information together.
Object[][][] sqlQuery = null; // No point giving it a dummy value

List<Object[][]> list = new ArrayList<Object[][]>();
...
sqlQuery = list.toArray(new Object[0][][]);
```

However, I'd *strongly* advise you not to go down this route anyway - encapsulate the "result" concept which is currently just `Object[][]` in a new type, so you'd have:

```
Result[] sqlQuery = null;

List<Result> list = new ArrayList<Result>();
...
sqlQuery = list.toArray(new Result[0]);
```

This will be a *lot* easier to reason about - even if `Result` only contains an `Object[][]`.

Answer (score 3):

```
sqlLista.toArray();
```

returns array where each element = Object[][], the return array's type is not Object[][] itself.

Change your code onto:

```
Object sqlQuery[][] = new Object[][] { };

List<Object[]> sqlLista = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
   while (resultSet.next()) {
      sqlLista.add(new Object[] { false, resultSet.getString("MMITNO"), null, null, null, null, null } );
   }

sqlQuery = sqlLista.toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the declaration of [List.toArray()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28%29).

It wants to convert to an array of Object (Object[]).
But `sqlQuery` is declared as an array *of an array* of Object (Object[][]).

What to do from here depends on what you want to achieve with your code. You may want to create a specific class for a row, and create a List of instances of that class, instead of an array of Object[][].